# CSV Format output

Tags: awk, sed, csv

I have the following situation:

A csv with users names and another Value (something like a serial number)

```
Test; User; WKCVW432994; ; ;
Test; Users; Middlename; WEJDFH34992; ;
Test; Some; Weird; Guy; WEFDJJ23453;
Test; Some; Even; Weirder; Guy; WEFDJJ23453
```

What I exactly need is to omit the delimiters and paste in a static value behind the name and before the serial number, like:

```
Test User StaticValue WKCVW432994
Test Users Middlename StaticValue WEJDFH34992
Test Some Weird Guy StaticValue WEFDJJ23453
Test Some Even Weirder Guy StaticValue WEFDJJ23453
```

I already got it managed for the guys with one fore and one surname:

```
awk -F";" '{k=$3; $3="StaticValue"; $4=k OFS $(NF--); print}' in.csv > out.csv
```

The difference between the name length / number of cells for the complete name I need is my problem at the moment.

Comment: Count from the end of the line, not from the start ;)

Comment: You should really work on fixing the format of the csv rather than working around it.  It's not sane data if the number of fields can change like that.

Comment: @Panki: I don't think that would help either because in OP's example there are random empty fields at the end of some of the lines for no apparent reason whatsoever.  Whatever created this file needs to be fixed.

Comment: Actually, there are always six fields (5 delimiters) in the examples given. The issue is that the serial number is in the field directly after the last component of the name. What the OP asks will actually make further processing of the file harder. The staticvalue should probably be -- a comma. Radical!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting from back is actually the right approach. On `GNU awk` you could try

```
awk -F ";" '{last=NF; while ($last ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/) last--; new=last+1; $new=$last; $last="StaticValue"; print}' in.csv  > out.csv
```

which would determine the last "non-empty" field by RegExp matching and inserting -- just as you did -- the "static value" before that.

For `mawk`, the syntax needs slight modification:

```
awk -F ";" '{last=NF; while ($last ~ /^ *$/) last--; new=last+1; $new=$last; $last="StaticValue"; print}' in.csv  > out.csv
```

Comment: It just helps for the longest one:
````
Test  User  WKCVW432994     StaticValue 

Test  Users  Middlename  WEJDFH34992   StaticValue 

Test  Some  Weird  Guy  WEFDJJ23453 StaticValue

Test  Some  Even  Weirder  Guy StaticValue  WEFDJJ23453


````

Comment: What happens if (for debugging) you just use `print last` after the `while ( ... ) last--;`?

Comment: It shows:
6
6
6
6
btw: my version is mawk 1.3.3

Comment: I see. I guess my syntax requires `GNU awk`. Perhaps I can come up with a `mawk`-compatible solution ...

Comment: THANKS a lot :) :) It works :)

Comment: Your first script will work in any POSIX awk, not just GNU awk. I can imagine needing the second one for **n**awk but I'd be surprised if **m**awk didn't support POSIX character classes.

Comment: @EdMorton I was surprised, too, but the OPs experience would indicate that indeed it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/;/,FS); $NF="StaticValue " $NF} 1' file
Test User StaticValue WKCVW432994
Test Users Middlename StaticValue WEJDFH34992
Test Some Weird Guy StaticValue WEFDJJ23453
Test Some Even Weirder Guy StaticValue WEFDJJ23453
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.